# Return closest matching value in seperate dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, lookup

**DATAFRAMES**

DataFrame 1

```
GENDER   HANDICAP   PRIMARYREC
 male      10        Model1
female     12        Model2
 male      18        Model3
```

DataFrame 2

```
MODEL1Lofts  MODEL2Lofts  MODEL3Lofts
    9             10.5        9
    10.5                     10.5
    12
```

**My current filter function:**

```
 driverfunc = driver_model[driver_model$Gender==gender &
                       driver_model$HandicapMin<=handicap & driver_model$HandicapMax>=handicap, ]
     return(driverfunc) }

**EXAMPLE INPUT** GetDriver(gender = "Male", handicap = 5)
```

Note: It automatically finds the recommended model

**GOAL**

What I'm looking to do is add a nested function within my filter (if possible) that includes the user inputting their "current loft" and then it lookups the possible values from DataFrame2 and adds that output to driverfunc.

This is literally my 4th day doing R and I've searched around a lot but getting stuck and any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of your dataframe(s?) using the `dput` function so we can reproduce it? Your filter function seems incomplete (there's an umatched curly brace and no function defintion). Also, It only seems to reference a single dataframe (the first?). Where does the second come in?

Comment: Sorry, just a total novice. The second dataframe is not yet referenced in the code at all. function (gender, handicap, current_shot_shape, desired_shot_shape) 
{
    driver_model <- read.csv("~/desktop/R Files/driver_model.csv")
    driverfunc = driver_model[driver_model$Gender == gender & 
        driver_model$CurrentShotShape == current_shot_shape & 
        driver_model$DesiredShotShape == desired_shot_shape & 
        driver_model$HandicapMin <= handicap & driver_model$HandicapMax >= 
        handicap, ]
    return(driverfunc)
}